# Mnemonic on Label for Text input field

Tags: java, swt, mnemonics

Having a `Label` and a `Text` control in SWT, how can I define a mnemonic on the label that will activate the input field? I found a couple of examples on how to set a mnemonic on a `Button`, but how do I define a mnemonic on a `Label` and make it point to a different input control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can define a mnemonic just as with a button.

```java
Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
label.setText( "&Name" );
Text text = new Text( parent, SWT.BORDER );
```

When pressing <kbd>Alt+N</kbd>, the control that is next in the tab order to the label will be focused, in this case, the text input field .

If another control should get the focus, you'll need to add a traverse listener to the label and manually give focus to the desired control.
For example

```java
Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
label.setText( "&Name" );
label.addListener( SWT.Traverse, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    if( event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_MNEMONIC ) {
      event.doit = false;
      otherControl.setFocus();
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this works on OSX and Linux as well?